# How to ignore exponential notification and get the actual value while importing data from excel into mysql

Tags: mysql, excel, csv, load-data-infile

I have a huge data in Excel. I need to import it into MySQL. I've saved my Excel file as CSV. There are several columns in my table which are having contact numbers. I've sat format for such fields to 'Number' with decimal places zero. When I saved it as CSV, its showing such values of such fields with Exponential Notification E+.

eg. Mobile_Number is 9840741284 but its showing 9.84E+09 in csv.

I am using MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE to view it. If I keep Mobile_Number column's datatype as int then it stores data as "2147483647" in mysql. All the records which are having Exponential sign are showing the same value in mysql which is 2147483647. That's why I changed the data type to varchar(255) from int. Now it showing result 9.84E+09 format. I am trying to import the data using load data infile command.

How to resolve it? Is there any other way to import data from excel to mysql as it is?

Answer (score 1):

I've changed the data type of Mobile_Numbers to bigint rather than only int in mysql. And its working properly. Thanks a lot Adyson for great help.